# Insert Face equally from all sides

Tags: modeling

I've been seaching for the past few hours and cant find an aswer that still works in blender (all the answers I can find on SE seems to be weofully outdated?)

How do I insert a new face with equal distance to all outlying edges?

No matter what I do, it always scale relative the scale of the cube (wether I scale the cube in edit or object mode, using scale or dimessions, doesn't matter, I can not for the life of me get it to simply insert the new face x units from all 4 edges.)

Please help.

Also, bonus question, what's the point of dimessions? as far as I can tell, they do exactly the same as scaling? (Insert and Loop Cut behave exactly identically regardless? ie. you cant use the viewports measurements to anything, since all the numbers are relative the the axies they are scalled along?)

Please note in the picture below, the cube was scaled in edit mide before using Insert, and I get the same result if I scale it in Object mode

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the main culprit behind the trouble you are having is because of non-uniform scale. What I mean by this, is that every time you scale an object in Object Mode, you should apply scale (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> > Scale), or it can and will cause a huge raft of issues later, from problems with texturing, to insets, to issues with curves and arrays.

Take this example - All I did was make a scene with 2 default cubes. One of the cubes (the one on the left) I scaled by 2 on the Z-axis in edit mode, and the other (the one on the right),  I scaled by the same amount in Object Mode. I then entered Edit Mode, and inset the front face of each of them by the same amount. I also added a horizontal and vertical loop cut around each so the "Edge Width" overlay will give more useful measurements.

[image: Scaling]

Notice the difference between the two - not just as to the shape of the inset, but also as to how "long" blender" thinks each of the edges are. (ie: the cube scaled in Object Mode "thinks" it's still the original 2M long on the Z-axis).

Comment: Yup! I'm just a massive dunce and a complete noob at blender evidently and did not know about the fact that you has to do ctrl-a Apply Scale, I can also see that Dimensions now appear to work correctly, thank you very much!

Comment: Hey, no problem. Don't worry - I think non-uniform scale is definitely on the top 10 list of all time noob mistakes. You're just like the rest of us.